# How can I import a scss file into another scss using hanami compiler?

Tags: sass, hanami

I have hanami v1.0.0 application with the folowing tree in apps/web/stylesheets:

```
├── favicon.ico
├── fonts
│   ├── glyphs
│   │   ├── winjs-symbols.eot
│   │   ├── winjs-symbols.ttf
│   │   └── winjs-symbols.woff
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── selawkb.eot
│   ├── selawkb.ttf
│   ├── selawk.eot
│   ├── selawkl.eot
│   ├── selawkl.ttf
│   ├── selawksb.eot
│   ├── selawksb.ttf
│   ├── selawksl.eot
│   ├── selawksl.ttf
│   └── selawk.ttf
├── images
├── javascripts
│   └── app.js
└── stylesheets
    ├── win
    │   ├── _resources.css.scss
    └── winstrap.css.scss
```

I import my _resources.css.scss file in winstrap.css.scss:

```
@import "win/resources";
```

But I recieved next error when hanami tried to load my assets:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: win/resources
```

How can I import _resources.css.scss file in winstrap.css.scss file?

Comment: Put an _ before resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed _resources.css.scss to _resources.scss and this fixed my error.